# Rails ActionMailer: Contact form - getting the right headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

On our webpage we have  a contact form to let people contact us without sharing our email addresses.

We require a name, an email address and a message and allow people to send a copy to themselves.

On our server we have Postfix setup to send outgoing email.

Right now we add information as:

- `from` = their email
- `to` = our email and theirs if they want a copy. (could be cc instead)

It works okay, but just some weeks ago Gmail started to put all our emails in junk, even with explicit rules and stuff.

We figured out our `Message-ID` have the wrong format and added

```
  def set_message_id(sent_at: Time.zone.now)
    headers["Message-ID"] = "<#{Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(sent_at.to_i.to_s)}@domain.com>"
  end
```

Based on an article from [Mailgun and StackOverflow](http://blog.mailgun.com/tips-tricks-avoiding-gmail-spam-filtering-when-using-ruby-on-rails-action-mailer/).

However we also get an SFP-softfail because we send the email from the users email, and the domain of their email does not have the same origin as our domain.

How do you solve this? We really like the way that you can instantly respond to a contact email and get the right name and email address automatically.

Is it worth investing in a service such as Mailgun just for this contact form?

Comment: I think best practice would be to use a `From` address that is actually correct and from the domain that the email is sent from. You can fill in the `Reply-To` header with the user's email address and name in the email that goes to you so. This way you can respond to the contact just as easily.

Comment: I thought about that as well, think I read that Gmail actually checks that the from and reply to should have same domain.